# What happens to the converting?

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm trying to get Coupon object from the Back-End, but in the Front-End I'm getting a 'Object' type, not Coupon type like I need.

I guess the problem is with the converting between the Back-End and the Front-End

Coupon JSON from the Back-End:

[image]

Coupon Entity in the Front-End:

```js
export class Coupon {

      amount: number
      category: number
      endDate: string
      id: number
      imageURL: string
      price: number
      startDate: string
      title: string

     
      constructor(
                id: number,
                // companyId: number,
                title: string,
                startDate: string,
                endDate: string,
                category: number,
                amount: number,
                price: number,
                imageURL: string
      ) {
                this.id = id
                // this.companyId = companyId
                this.title = title
                this.startDate = startDate
                this.endDate = endDate
                this.category = category
                this.amount = amount
                this.price = price
                this.imageURL = imageURL
      }
}
```

GET request:

```js
getCompanyCoupons() {
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set("token", this.token);
  return this.http.get < Coupon[] > ('http://localhost:8080/api/company/get_company_coupons', {
    params
  })
}
```

Using the request:

```js
fetchAllCoupons() {
  this.storagService.getCompanyCoupons()
    .subscribe(coupons => {
      this.coupons = coupons
      console.log(this.coupons)
    })
}
```

Comment: From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: not sure, but you probably have to loop through the coupons and convert them all to Coupon one at a time.

Comment: yes (not javascript - sry for the wrong 'tag'.

Comment: @Avinadav I think they meant it's not Java. At least javascript is valid typescript

Comment: @Rick No.... but thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an example of the JSON as text, not as an image of text. One easy way of getting that text (if the structure allows) is to use `console.log(JSON.sttringify(obj, null, 2))` and copy and past the output into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript types do not exist at runtime, and Javascript classes cannot be encoded in JSON.

Retaining the class when sending data over the wire will require an encoding that's no JSON. I'm not aware of a popular format that serializes/deserializes class names.

Probably the right route for this is to accept that your classes are going to plain objects when serializing to JSON, and if you want to turn that into a class again on the other side, you will have to do some manual work to do this.